# AnimatedBuilder not working when trying to avoid setState call inside add listener

Tags: flutter, animation, setstate

I had copy pasted code for an animated button that calls setState as it adds a listener to the animation controller.

This article and SO answer:

[(Article) Flutter Laggy Animations: How Not To setState](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-laggy-animations-how-not-to-setstate-f2dd9873b8fc)

[(SO answer) Flutter animation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743794/flutter-animation-not-working)

stated that calling setState is not recommended in this case because it will rebuild the entire UI each time the button is pressed. Makes sense!

Now when I do use the AnimatedBuilder stops working. What am I doing wrong?

The Code:

```
class _AnimatedButtonState extends State<AnimatedButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final style = GoogleFonts.volkhov(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 15,
  );
  double _scale;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        lowerBound: 0.0,
        upperBound: 0.1);
    // _controller.addListener(() {
    //   setState(() {});
    // });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scale = 1 - _controller.value;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _onTap,
      onTapDown: _onTapDown,
      onTapUp: _onTapUp,
      onTapCancel: _onTapCancel,
      child: AnimatedBuilder(           // HERE HERE
          animation: _controller,
          child: _animatedButtonUI,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Transform.scale(
              scale: _scale,
              child: child,
            );
          },
      )
    );
  }

  _onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) => _controller.reverse();
  _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) => _controller.forward();
  _onTapCancel() => _controller.reverse();

  Widget get _animatedButtonUI => Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 250,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        colors: [Colors.green, Colors.green[400], Colors.green[500]],
      ),
    ),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        'Save',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Side-note: The reason I found this tip, was because I was trying to make my button more responsive to click/touch. Quick clicks and touches on the phone, did not trigger the animation when I used the setState. Instead it took longer than a casual touch by the user.
If you can help me with that as well, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: In this case, `setState` does not seem like it would be very expensive as the whole widget is just the button which is the only thing to be animated. Using `AnimatedBuilder` provides little to no benefit.

Comment: I thought so as well. It's just the first I came across AnimatedBuilder so I wanted to use it.

Comment: It works well in other cases where the stateful widget contains more, as in the article you posted. See my answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `_scale`, which you are using as the value for the animation, is not being updated due to a lack of `setState`. The only place `_scale` is being updated is in the stateful widget's build method. The only time `build` is called again after the first time is when `setState` is called, leading to `_scale` not being updated like you wanted.

`AnimatedBuilder` is essentially the same as you would do by calling `setState`, but it isolates the rebuild to just the `builder` of itself rather than the enclosing stateful widget as a whole, which is why it's considered better for performance.

To solve this, simply move `_scale = 1 - _controller.value;` into the `builder` of `AnimatedBuilder`.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  //_scale = 1 - _controller.value; NOT HERE
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: _onTap,
    onTapDown: _onTapDown,
    onTapUp: _onTapUp,
    onTapCancel: _onTapCancel,
    child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        child: _animatedButtonUI,
        builder: (context, child) {
          _scale = 1 - _controller.value; //HERE
          return Transform.scale(
            scale: _scale,
            child: child,
          );
        },
    )
  );
}
```